# Get pinged in your discord server when your number of subscribers increases

Tags: python-3.x, youtube, discord.py

So I want my discord bot to ping me in my server if my youtube subscriber count increases (even by 1) by using python. I am new to python so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [`background_task.py`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/cb587f67bae4316d7acdd95b225237985022d9aa/examples/background_task.py) from `discord.py` examples:

```
from discord.ext import tasks

import discord

from googleapiclient.discovery import build


class YouTubeCheckClient(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)    
            
        youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey = 'YOUR_YOUTUBE_API_KEY')

        # two attributes we can access from our task
        self.latestSubscriberCount = None
        self.request = youtube.channels().list(part = 'statistics', id = 'YOUR_YOUTUBE_CHANNEL_ID')

    async def setup_hook(self) -> None:
        # start the check to run in the background
        self.youtube_background_check.start()

    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'Logged in as {self.user} (ID: {self.user.id})')
        print('------')

    # Check runs every 9 seconds as YouTube Data API v3 default quota per day is 10,000 and Channels: list costs 1 of quota.
    @tasks.loop(seconds=9)
    async def youtube_background_check(self):
        channel = self.get_channel('YOUR_DISCORD_CHANNEL_ID')
        
        result = self.request.execute()
        subscriberCount = int(result['items'][0]['statistics']['subscriberCount'])
        print(subscriberCount)
        if self.latestSubscriberCount == None:
            self.latestSubscriberCount = subscriberCount
        if subscriberCount > self.latestSubscriberCount:
            await channel.send(f'<@YOUR_DISCORD_USER_ID> your YouTube subscriber count increases by {subscriberCount - self.latestSubscriberCount}!')
        self.latestSubscriberCount = subscriberCount

    @youtube_background_check.before_loop
    async def before_youtube_check(self):
        await self.wait_until_ready()  # wait until the bot logs in


client = YouTubeCheckClient(intents=discord.Intents.default())
client.run('YOUR_DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN')
```

Basically this code setups a Discord bot connection to your Discord channel and retrieves every 9 seconds the subscriber count of your YouTube channel and if it increases, it pings you on the given Discord channel.

Don't forget to replace:

- `YOUR_YOUTUBE_API_KEY` with your [YouTube Data API v3 key](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application)
- `YOUR_YOUTUBE_CHANNEL_ID` with your YouTube channel id such as [`UCv_LqFI-0vMVYgNR3TeB3zQ`](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCv_LqFI-0vMVYgNR3TeB3zQ)
- `YOUR_DISCORD_CHANNEL_ID` with your Discord channel id that you can get by right-clicking the given Discord channel
- `YOUR_DISCORD_USER_ID` with your Discord user id that you can get by right-clicking your Discord user
- `YOUR_DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN` with your Discord bot token that you can get by following [this procedure](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/discord.html)

Comment: Hi 
When I try it, I keep getting this error

Comment: [2022-10-15 18:17:21] [ERROR] discord.ext.tasks: Unhandled exception in internal background task 'youtube_background_check'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\tasks\__init__.py", line 239, in _loop
    await self.coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Downloads\BOT.py", line 37, in youtube_background_check
    await channel.send(self.client.get_channel(123456789987654321), f'<@Shivesh08> your YouTube subscriber count increased by {subscriberCount - self.latestSubscriberCount}!')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Comment: Just to make sure: are you using a correct Discord channel id other than `123456789987654321`?

Comment: Yes I used a proper channel id